# ubuntu gnome 15.10 error with using bumblebee optirun: KMS not enabled

Tags: nvidia, gnome, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a fresh installation of ubuntu gnome 15.10 and I cannot get bumblebee optirun to work.  My laptop has the optimus setup with Intel and Nvidia graphics cards. I get the following error trying to use optirun:

```
~$optirun firefox
[ 4580.965189] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) [drm] KMS not enabled

[ 4580.965358] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I thought KMS was enabled by default with newer kernels but I'm not certain of this.  Do I need to use bbswitch first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove bumblebee and use nvidia-prime to switch between the two graphics solutions instead.

First identify your NVIDIA graphics hardware - open a terminal and execute:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

Search for available drivers on the [NVIDIA Drivers website](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us).

**Update :**

Uninstall every NVIDIA related software ...

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia* bumblebee  
sudo reboot
```

**Update :**

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers ...

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter user name and password - then execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Use the NVIDIA X Server Settings application (**Prime Profiles**) to switch between the two GPU's.

Comment: Yes, I am a new user to this group.  I did follow the instructions above and my desktop has now completely failed.  I'm hoping I don't have to reinstall everything, I was really in love with it.

Comment: @user3174452 What graphics card do you have and which drivers did you install ?

Comment: It's an nvidia geforce 840m card and I installed the nvidia-358* driver I believe.

Comment: @user3174452 There must have  been something going wrong with the installation process ... I will update the answer with an alternative way to install and include the latest long-lived branch drivers ... please stay tuned - it will take a few minutes. :)

Comment: Do you not recommend purging nouveau?  I would prefer not to.

Comment: @user3174452 : I did not recommend to purge nouveau ! The parameter disables nouveau when booting the PC to avoid complications when installing the proprietary NVIDIA drivers . :)

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for your help.  So far so good on my end here.

Comment: @user3174452 : You're welcome - enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)